# css modal backdrop doesn't fill height when address bar collapses on mobile

Tags: css, progressive-web-apps

React Frontend
Material-ui backdrop
Chrome Browser

On mobile, for PWAs the header will collapse if you scroll down; when this happens the backdrop leaves a gap on the bottom of the screen the height of the address bar.

What can I do to set the backdrop to fill the gap?

Thanks!
( Ignore the silly dummy data :-D )

```
    <Backdrop
        className={modalBemify("modal_backdrop")}
        open={open}
        onClick={closeCallback}
        style={{ zIndex: 1, color: "#fff" }}
    >
        <div
            className={modalBemify("modal")}
            open={open}
        >
            <Fade in={open}>
                <DefaultMargin modifier="modal"> 
                    <div className={modalBemify("modal_paper")}>
                        {props.children}
                    </div>
                </DefaultMargin>
            </Fade>
        </div>
    </Backdrop>
```

[image: Modal closed, with address bar]
[image: Modal open w/ address bar]
[image: Modal open w/out address bar]

You can see the 3rd image has a gap in the transparent background when the address bar collapses.

Comment: Create an example (with CODE) where we can reproduce your backend. We can't do anything just with pictures.

Comment: The address bar only collapses with a downloaded PWA - I'm looking for an answer from someone who has come across this before - otherwise I need to create a whole dummy PWA to give people a way to test

Comment: you don't your PWA is just some html + css. create an example with html+css and then we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the background from the material-ui `Backdrop` component (`background-color: unset !important;`) and added it to the `.modal` class (`background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 95%);`)